# mail is not sending yahoo small business

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpmailer, yahoo

I am trying to send email using Laravel via yahoo small business but I am getting This error please help me.

[This is what I am getting an error(Image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73nm3.jpg)

[My .env file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te48W.png)

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com

MAIL_PORT=465

MAIL_USERNAME=****@yahoo.com

MAIL_PASSWORD=*******

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

[My Send email Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm2ba.png)

```
public function index()
{
    $this->sendMail('mails.subscribe', '******@****.**', '******@**.**', 
    'Testing', 'Test');
}

public function sendMail($bladeName, $from, $to, $subject, $body)
    {
        Mail::send(['html' => $bladeName], ['user' => $body], function 
        ($message) use ($to, $subject, $from) {
        $message->to($to)->subject($subject);
        $message->from($from, 'Test');
    });
}
```

Comment: Post your code as text

Comment: Can you post your Mail class code

Comment: updated .env file and controller code

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the smtp port to : 587

Sorry for my other answer I overlooked your code.

your mail function is wrong that's why you are not connecting

try :

```
    Mail::send('emails.welcome', ['key' => 'value'], function($message)
{
    $message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

One more :

```
 Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)

{
    $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');

$message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');

$message->attach($pathToFile);
});
```